# Can I get my old keyboard back after update?

Tags: keyboard, swype

I have an HTC Desire X and I Updated Android yesterday (I have android 4.1.1 now).
Since the update I have a new keyboard, which has keys on different places (such as the change language button). Also the Swype (or trace or whats-it-called) function is gone.

The picture below was my old keyboard, is there a way to get this keyboard back?

[image: Old keyboard]

I already looked in `Settings > Language & keyboard` where I found HTC Sense input, but there is no possibility to turn on trace (or Swype) there or the option to select my old keyboard.

Comment: It might help if you could say what keyboard it was, a picture alone can just make guesses possible. There are multiple keyboards supporting "swype input", most of them are available at Google Play: like the "original" [Swype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.swype.trial), [Swiftkey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey.phone.trial), [SlideIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dasur.slideit.vt.lite) (looks very much like your screenshot), [TouchPal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cootek.smartinputv5)...

Comment: It was the keyboard that was on my phone when I bought it. I did try some Keyboard apps, but I like the old one better.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that the Swype option disappeared with the upgrade.  At first, I was really annoyed.  Then I downloaded the Swype trial from Play.  It is so much better than what I had before that I have no hesitation in paying the $0.99 to get the full-blown Swype.

Comment: using touchpall now, which is also quite good. i just find it weird that you get a downgrade with an update

Answer (score 1):

I checked a few alternatives and found that the free [Go keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard) is the closest match to the old HTC Desire X one as the spacebar is longer and easier to press.

However, my phone gets slower whenever I want to open the keyboard to type like sms, Whatsapp,etc. Could be that the app is slowing down the phone. I wish they had include the swype keyboard in their latest software update. Kind of weird that they have taken out a function for an update.

Answer (score -1):

As soon as your keyboard appears, pull down the notifications center.

There you should see a notification "Choose Input Method", tap it.

A menu dialog should appear allowing you to choose a different keyboard.

Comment: I does offer HTC keyboard but this one is not the old one